# Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException "An exception occurred while executing '...' with params [...] Warning: Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=

Tags: mysql, azure, symfony, doctrine

Context : a Symfony 4.4 web app hosted on Ubuntu-based Docker image on Azure Web App connected to a MySQL 5.7 Azure Database for MySQL .

We have MANY (>5K events in Sentry per 14 days) errors like :

---

**Case 1**

```
Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException

An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT qd.id as uuid, qd.content as content FROM queue_data qd WHERE qd.tag = ? LIMIT 1000' with params [...]:

Warning: Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=...
```

Coming from :

```php
    // App\Utility\Queue\Service\QueueDataService::getData
    
    public function getData(string $tag, int $limit = self::DEFAULT_LIMIT): array
    {
        return $this->getQueryBuilderForTag($tag)
            ->select('qd.id as uuid', 'qd.content as content')
            ->setMaxResults($limit)
            ->execute()
            ->fetchAll(FetchMode::ASSOCIATIVE);
    }
```

**Case 2**

```
Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException

An exception occurred while executing 'SET NAMES utf8mb4':

Warning: Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=...
```

Coming from :

```php
// custom code

private function myMethod(){
    ...
    $this->connection->executeQuery('SET NAMES utf8mb4');
    ...
}
```

...

---

Sentry shows 245 "issues" with this message (over 14 days) => that's 245 different cases of the same problem, each instance having between 1 and 2K events (some instances actually come from consumers that are executed VERY frequently).

Nevertheless, it doesn't seem to have any impact on users...

Does anyone else have the same issues ?
Is it possible to fix this ?
How ?

Cheers !

Comment: to be honest the problem seems to be outside of symfony/doctrine and either in the communication between php (pdo) and the database server. error while sending query packet sounds like a network issue. I suppose you might get better answers on serverfault or even from azure support.

Comment: Thanks @Jakumi . I think so too that this might be a network issue, but howcome this happens so many times and has no visible impact on our users ?
Azure support is truly useless.

Comment: it appears from the error messages, that it does fail all over the place. so either it's a driver problem, network problem or db problem. you could try to reproduce it on a new instance, but if it's still the same, it's probably not the driver ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue :

- on my DB server (MySQL), I had the parameter `wait_timeout` set to 120 seconds
- I have several message consumer processes managed by Supervisor
- these workers consume several messages per process, and had no `time-limit` , so they could be waiting for a new message to consume for more than 2 minutes
- in that case, the DB server had closed the DB connection, but the Doctrine client was not aware of that until it tried to execute a request that would fail

My fix was to :

- increase the DB server config `wait_timeout` to 600 seconds (10 minutes)
- add a `time-limit` of 300 seconds (5 minutes) to my consumer processes

The root cause should still be addressed by the Doctrine team : it seams weird that it doesn't ping the server (test if the connection is still open) before trying to execute a query.

Cheers !